# Kotlin contract which helps compiler smartcast all list elements from nullable to non-nullable?

Tags: kotlin

following situation: I try to implement a generic function, which checks if a list of variables are all not null and executes a lambda, which requires non-nullable variables.

I can chain multiple let-calls or implement multiple 'safeLet'-Function, with 2,3,4... arguments, but I still hope one generic function with a list is possible.

Here the current code, with chained let-calls:

```
val parameters = call.receiveParameters()
val firstName = parameters["firstName"]
val lastName = parameters["lastName"]

firstName?.let {
    lastName?.let { userService.add(UserDTO(firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName)) }
}
```

Here is my current 'safeLet' function:

```
fun  <T> List<Any?>.safeLet(block: () -> T) {
    if(this.contains(null)) return

    block()
}
```

But following still doesn't compile (because parameters of UserDTO are String and not String?):

```
listOf(firstName, lastName).safeLet {
    userService.add(UserDTO(firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName))
}
```

I can add !! after firstName and lastName to avoid the nullcheck, but that's ugly.

My idea is to use kotlin contracts. Is something possible like this:

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun  <T> List<Any?>.safeLet(block: () -> T) {
    contract {
        returnsNotNull() implies {ALL ELEMENTS ARE NOT NULLABLE}
    }    

    if(this.contains(null)) return

    block()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

In relation to the "filterNotNull" comment i now tried this. Still not ideal, because I don't like to use this[0] and this[1] here, but it works:

```
allNotNull(firstName, lastName)?.apply {
    userService.add(UserDTO(firstName = this[0], lastName = this[1]))
}


fun <T : Any> allNotNull(vararg elements: T?): List<T>? = if(elements.contains(null)) null else elements.filterNotNull()
```

Comment: `filterNoNull()`?

Comment: No idea, how filterNotNull can work here. The compiler can smartcast my list from List<Any?> to List<Any> as a result of this, but this doesn't help to smartcast my list elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `binding` function. It accepts another function inside of which you can use `bind` to transform nullable reference to not-null one.

If you pass a not-null argument to `bind`, it returns it. Otherwise, it suspends the execution of the `binding` block.

If the execution is suspended, `binding` returns `null`, otherwise it returns a result of the `binding` block.

---

Here is how you can use `binding`:

```
binding { userService.add(UserDTO(firstName = firstName.bind(), lastName = lastName.bind())) }
```

One more example:

```
fun sumOrNull(a: Int?, b: Int?): Int? = binding { a.bind() + b.bind() }
```

---

Here is my `binding` implementation:

```
// startCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn returns either COROUTINE_SUSPENDED or R
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <R> binding(block: suspend Binder.() -> R): R? =
    when (val result = block.startCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn(Binder, BinderContinuation)) {
        COROUTINE_SUSPENDED -> null
        else -> result as R
    }

@RestrictsSuspension
object Binder {
    suspend fun <T> T?.bind(): T {
        if (this != null) return this
        suspendCoroutine<Nothing> {}
    }
}

suspend fun <T> Binder.bind(obj: T?): T {
    contract {
        returns() implies (obj != null)
    }
    return obj.bind()
}

private object BinderContinuation : Continuation<Any?> {
    override val context: CoroutineContext
        get() = EmptyCoroutineContext

    override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Any?>) {
        result.getOrThrow()
    }
}
```